# Match a whole sentence only if it's at the end of a string

Tags: javascript

Let's say we want to check if `speech` contains a specific sentence (`reference`) **but at the last and end of it**:

Here is the `reference`:

```
let reference = "have you ever look at someone";
```

Based on this `reference` we want to compare `speech` and return match or No match:

```
let speech = "blaaaah have you ever look at someone"; // Match because 'have you ever look at someone' is at the end of speech
let speech = "have you ever look at someone blaaaah"; // No match because something else came after 'have you ever look at someone'
```

The problem is I can't differentiate between above speech examples and the code always returns Match:

```js
//let speech = "blaaaah have you ever look at someone"; // matched
let speech = "have you ever look at someone blaaaah"; // No match 

let reference = "have you ever look at someone";

if(new RegExp("\\b"+reference+"\\b").test(speech)){
  console.log("Finally Matched!")
} else {
  console.log("No Match At Last!")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
//let speech = "blaaaah have you ever look at someone"; // matched
let speech = "have you ever look at someone blaaaah"; // No match 

let reference = "have you ever look at someone";

if(new RegExp("\\b"+reference+"\\b$").test(speech)){
  console.log("Finally Matched!")
} else {
  console.log("No Match At Last!")
}
```

Comment: I should confess that I wouldn't find that $ sign in days ... Thanks for the great answer...

Answer (score 1):

you can use `endsWith` to validate as follows,

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.endsWith("universe.");
```

in your case

```
  //let speech = "blaaaah have you ever look at someone"; // matched
let speech = "have you ever look at someone blaaaah"; // No match 

let reference = "have you ever look at someone";

if(speech.endsWith(reference)){
  console.log("Finally Matched!")
} else {
  console.log("No Match At Last!")
}
```